# Wrong properties from frame of image in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have an array of images that are created within a CGRect frame

.h file:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
```

.m file:

```
 myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[imageArray addObject:myImage];
```

If I call the frame directly from the myImage variable I get the correct values:

```
NSLog(@"Frame x:%f y:%f w:%f h:%f", myImage.frame.origin.x, myImage.frame.origin.y, myImage.frame.size.width, myImage.frame.size.height);
```

Outputs: `frame x:226.000000 y:226.000000 w:226.000000 h:334.000000``

But if I call the image through the array it gives me incorrect values:

```
UIImageView *anImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:5];        
NSLog(@"frame x:%f y:%f w:%f h:%f", anImage.frame.origin.x, anImage.frame.origin.y, anImage.frame.size.width, anImage.frame.size.height);
```

Outputs: `frame x:0.000000 y:0.000000 w:0.000000 h:0.000000`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you alloc+init the imagArray?

Comment: I'd bet $1 on @AnoopVaidya 's theory.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be dong wrong is initialization of the array

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
```

Tried

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
UIImageView *  myImage ;
CGRect myImageRect=CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    myImage= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [imageArray addObject:myImage];

}
UIImageView *anImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:3];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(anImage.frame));
```

Result

```
2013-04-03 01:10:49.114 TrialsError[95088:11303] {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}
```